# API 10: Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) - ActionBarActivity vs FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

As long as one wants to support API 10: Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread), why or when would you really want to use FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity? Is there any good reason for doing so? Because ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity and so offers all the features of FragmentActivity out of the box. I have seen sample codes all over the internet which use FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity and hence was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
why or when would you really want to use FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity?
```

Since `fragment` introduce since `api 11/honeycomb` you can not really use it from api 10 which `FragmentActivity` is made to backport fragment to lower level api.

For `ActionBarActivity` if you want to use actionbar within your application then you need to use this, that is because `The action bar has been introduced in Android 3.0.` same as fragment.

Therefore if you want just fragment no actionbar in your application ranging from `gingerbread` and below then `FragmentActivity` is the way to go hence if you want to support `actionbar` with `fragments` capabilities in your application with devices `gingerbread` and below API then `ActionBarActivity` must be used.